# How to tar from different locations and untar on same locations in Java?

Tags: java, tar

Suppose I have 3 different locations

```
/1/data_files/
/2/user/data/
/3/temp/files/
```

What I wish to do here is tar the files under 'data_files', 'data' and 'files' in one tgz bundle on say master node. Stream it to slave node and untar on same locations on slave node. I'm not asking for streaming logic. All I wanna know is how to tar and untar in such scenario in JAVA.

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? Do you mean "jar" by any chance?

Comment: I need it in java only. I have to add this functionality in some part of my code. And its 'tar' not 'jar'. I meant using TarInputStream and TarOutputStream.

Comment: Very well. Show us what you have done so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't done anything so far. I'm just confused on how to go about it. One thing that I thought of was taring all the directories individually and then make a master tar having all the individual tar's of the dirs.

Comment: You know, the rules say "question asking for code must show a minimal understanding" and so on. So did you ever use the TarOutputStream, to begin with?

Comment: Yeah. I have used tar streaming. But I've done that just from one absolute path and have extracted to same one, on another node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it like thus:

```
create your taroutputstream
for each directory
  change directory there
  for each file
      make a TarEntry, add it to the stream and write the file data
close your taroutputstream
check with tar -tvf ... or some such.
```

The trick is that you change the directory so that the files below this can be referenced with a relative name. This corresponds to the -C option of the tar command:

```
tar -cvf /tmp/narch.tar -C /1 . -C /2 . -C /3 .
```

would be the tar command for your example.
Note that not all tar implementations will support multiple -C options, so the following would also work:

```
tar -cvf /tmp/narch.tar -C /1 .
tar -uvf /tmp/narch.tar -C /2 .
tar -uvf /tmp/narch.tar -C /3 .
```